# Disallow single quoted values in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I'm parsing a Json file which should be formatted according to json's formal specification, which doesn't include the possibility of wrapping keys and values in single quotes ('). However, using either `org.json` or `gson`, the implementation is accepting those entries and successfully converting the file to a `JsonObject`. I need that to fail (there is a second validation in my flow which doesn't allow single quotes).

I've been looking into ways of configuring the parsers so that they fail. I've read that `Jackson`'s  `JsonParser` doesn't allow that by default, having then the possibility to explicitly change that. Could I do the same with one of the previously mentioned libraries, or should I use `Jackson` instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use Jackson?

Comment: I was trying to avoid adding more dependencies to this project. To be honest, `org.json` would be preferable to both `gson` and `Jackson` as it's already being used by another module.

Comment: If you have already converted to a JSON Object then why does it matter what the quotes were since they no longer exist in the data?

Comment: @Deadron Question already says why: *"I need that to fail (there is a second validation in my flow which doesn't allow single quotes)."* --- OP wants early failure on invalid JSON.

Comment: @Andreas I am sure you are aware that not everyone crafts the perfect question. Its also important because not all JSON parsers parse the entire object up front.  If he is trying to validate JSON vs parse its important to know.

Comment: @Deadron Then you asked the wrong question in your comment. OP obviously has a flow where (at least) two of the steps parses the JSON, probably because re-serializing the parse data between steps would be redundant. If you wanted to know whether that first parsing is done purely for validation purposes, then you should have asked that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.json` is open-source, so you can build a modified version that doesn't allow single-quoted string literals.

In the `JSONTokener` class, modify the [`nextValue()`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/9de97438acf1f23e8a4e3846ff0534858672298f/src/main/java/org/json/JSONTokener.java#L414) method.

```java
public Object nextValue() throws JSONException {
    char c = this.nextClean();
    String string;

    switch (c) {
    case '"':
    case '\'': // ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← REMOVE OR COMMENT THIS LINE
        return this.nextString(c);
    case '{':
        this.back();
        return new JSONObject(this);
    case '[':
        this.back();
        return new JSONArray(this);
    }
    
    ...
```